# aws_key_pair.kyc_app_public_key: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I always get this error on my terraform. How do I fix this?

> aws_key_pair.kyc_app_public_key: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format

I already generated the ssh with this command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -b 2048 -C "assignment"`

Here is my configuration script on terraform

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "kyc_app_public_key" {
  key_name = "assignment"
  public_key ="//~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}
```

Comment: Does that path actually work? Why do you have `//` before `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`?

Answer (score 7):

So if you go through the [official document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html), the `public_key` is the content of the public key file.

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
  key_name   = "deployer-key"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD3F6tyPEFEzV0LX3X8BsXdMsQz1x2cEikKDEY0aIj41qgxMCP/iteneqXSIFZBp5vizPvaoIR3Um9xK7PGoW8giupGn+EPuxIA4cDM4vzOqOkiMPhz5XK0whEjkVzTo4+S0puvDZuwIsdiW9mxhJc7tgBNL0cYlWSYVkz4G/fslNfRPW5mYAM49f4fhtxPb5ok4Q2Lg9dPKVHO/Bgeu5woMc7RY0p1ej6D4CKFE6lymSDJpW0YHX/wqE9+cfEauh7xZcG0q9t2ta6F6fmX0agvpFyZo8aFbXeUBr7osSCJNgvavWbM/06niWrOvYX2xwWdhXmXSrbX8ZbabVohBK41 email@example.com"
}
```

If you want to reference the file name, more than content, use function `file()`

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "kyc_app_public_key" {
  key_name = "assignment"
  public_key = "${file("//~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}"
}
```

I am not 100% sure if works with your way `//~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, normally I copy the public key to local folder and reference as

```
public_key = "${file("${path.module}/id_rsa.pub")}"
```